# Route Call in Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I have a scenario in which I want to route calls to sip a server from Asterisk but I want to do some thing like this

the sip server is running on : 192.168.1.10 and 
Asterisk server is running on : 192.168.1.4

`client Diales---->sip:111@192.168.1.4---->To Asterisk and then Asterisk route the` `calls------->sip:111@192.168.1.10 --------> sip server`

Can someone tell me how can I do this in Asterisk configuration routing file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As os11k said, you need SIP trunk to do this. I'll add some detail information about issues we encountered when we setup SIP trunk between two cities.

### Add a SIP trunk in sip.conf

- Make sure you put `sendrpid=yes` in the SIP trunk configuration, or, 192.168.1.10 will not get the caller id.
- Optionally, you may want to set context of the SIP trunk to a different context rather than `default`, say `context=sip-server-192-168-1-10`.
- Optionally, you may disallow or allow some codecs if 192.168.1.10 only works with specific codecs.

**SIP trunk sample**

```
[general]
register => SIP_ACCOUNT:SIP_PASSWORD@TheOtherSipServer

[TheOtherSipServer]
type=peer
context=sip-server-192-168-1-10

host=192.168.1.10
defaultuser=THE_ACCOUNT_HERE
fromuser=THE_ACCOUNT_HERE
remotesecret=THE_PASSWORD_OF_ACCOUNT_HERE

; if you want to send the remote caller id to 192.168.1.10, then set sendrpid=yes .
; you also need to trust the remote caller id in 192.168.1.10 .
sendrpid=yes

; if 192.168.1.10 can dial out from here, you need to set trustrpid=yes so you can get the caller id
;trustrpid=yes

; if 192.168.1.10 is picky on codecs
;disallow=all
;allow=THE_CODEC_NAME_ALLOWED_BY_THE_OTHER_SIP_SERVER
```

### Setup dial plan in extensions.conf

`Dial` is all you needed unless you need special requirement.

**Dialplan sample**

```
[globals]
SIPTrunk=SIP/TheOtherSipServer

[sip-server-192-168-1-10]
;exten=>111,1,Dial(SIP/TheOtherSipServer/111)
exten=>111,1,Dial(${SIPTrunk}/${EXTEN})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set-up sip trunk on your Asterisk server.

Check this page for more info:

https://www.beardy.se/how-to-set-up-a-sip-trunk-in-the-asterisk-pbx

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf